# How to get simultaneous keyboard input in pygame

Tags: python, pygame, game-development

I'm developing a rhythm game using pygame, and I'm stuck on getting simultaneous keyboard inputs.
When keys are pressed in the game, the keybeam should be viewed on the screen.

However, if I press multiple keys at the same time, the beams don't appear at once. They lag and appear separately.

What should I do to solve this problem?

My code:

```
import pygame

pygame.init()


WIDTH = 1280
HEIGHT = 720
FPS = 60

SCREEN = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))
pygame.display.set_caption('Rhythmetric')
pygame.event.set_allowed([pygame.QUIT, pygame.KEYDOWN, pygame.KEYUP, pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN])

clock = pygame.time.Clock()


pink_keybeam = pygame.image.load('img/pink_keybeam.png').convert_alpha()


is_running = True

while is_running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            is_running = False
        
    SCREEN.fill((0, 0, 0))
    if pygame.key.get_pressed()[pygame.K_d]:
        SCREEN.blit(pink_keybeam, (440, 0))
    if pygame.key.get_pressed()[pygame.K_f]:
        SCREEN.blit(pink_keybeam, (540, 0))
    if pygame.key.get_pressed()[pygame.K_j]:
        SCREEN.blit(pink_keybeam, (640, 0))
    if pygame.key.get_pressed()[pygame.K_k]:
        SCREEN.blit(pink_keybeam, (740, 0))


    pygame.display.update() 
    clock.tick(FPS)


pygame.quit()
```

Comment: It doesn't look like you're using [`pygame.key.get_pressed`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/key.html#pygame.key.get_pressed) correctly.

Answer (score -1):

Based on some of the pygame documentation examples, they declare a `main` function to run the game loop.

A possible solution to your problem might look like this:

```py
import os

import pygame

MAIN_DIR = os.path.split(os.path.abspath(__file__))[0]
WIDTH = 1280
HEIGHT = 720
FPS = 60


def load_image(name):
    path = os.path.join(MAIN_DIR, "img", name)
    return pygame.image.load(path).convert_alpha()


def main():
    pygame.init()
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))
    pygame.display.set_caption('Rhythmetric')
    pygame.event.set_allowed([pygame.QUIT, pygame.KEYDOWN, pygame.KEYUP, pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN])

    clock = pygame.time.Clock()

    pink_keybeam = load_image("pink_keybeam.png")

    while True:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                return

        screen.fill((0, 0, 0))

        keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()

        if keys[pygame.K_d]:
            screen.blit(pink_keybeam, (440, 0))
        if keys[pygame.K_f]:
            screen.blit(pink_keybeam, (540, 0))
        if keys[pygame.K_j]:
            screen.blit(pink_keybeam, (640, 0))
        if keys[pygame.K_k]:
            screen.blit(pink_keybeam, (740, 0))

        clock.tick(FPS)
        pygame.display.update()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
    pygame.quit()
```

I tested this code, and it works fine, which you can see in the following screenshot:

- Pressing two keys at the same time:
  [image]

Lastly, I would recommend you to check if you have installed system dependencies for pygame based on your OS. You can find more information about it [here](https://www.pygame.org/wiki/GettingStarted#Pygame%20Installation).